# I need actionbar to use one theme and viewpageindicator to use another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have a theme that I created from the Android Asset Studio, which has my actionbar looking how i want it. I also have Cheesebaron's [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator) in my project. In order for the styles to show up on the ViewPager, I am setting the activity's theme to "@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults". All is dandy, except the ViewPagerIndicator theme overwrites my actionbar theme. Is there a way to only apply the ViewPagerIndicator theme to just the ViewPager?

I am using AppCompat action bar, not ActionBarSherlock. I hope this enough information. Thanks to everyone.